# Selenium Python, auto-click until another element appears

Tags: python, function, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to have my selenium webdriver in python auto-click on a button until a pop up shows up that i can click on. my code looks like this:

```
cart_count = "0"

def add_to_cart_click():
"""
clicks to add to your cart
:return:
"""
   add=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pdp_addtocart_button"]')
   add.click()
   check_cart()

def check_cart():
"""
checks to see if you have the item inside your cart
:return:
"""
   global cart_count
   if cart_count == "0":
     update_cart_count()
     print(cart_count)
   if cart_count == "1":
      wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
      go_to_cart=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='header_cart_button']")))
      go_to_cart.click()
      cart()
   else:
      print('IDK')

def update_cart_count():
"""
updates your cart when you got a pair, I think
:return:
"""

   global cart_count
   new_cart_count = driver.find_element_by_id('header_cart_count')
   cart_count = new_cart_count.text
```

then it calls the functions in the right order, what am i doing wrong? it seems to me that the cart_count doesn't update. how can I make it contentiously check and update its value? it usually prints out 0 IDK 0 IDK then stops, if anyone has an idea please let me know. thank you

Comment: Share `URL` as it's not quite clear what you actually intend to get as output

Comment: what do you mean it stops? i'm not familiar with python but do you really have to define cart_count with `global cart_count` inside every function that uses it?